# No sidebar on product category (woocommerce) page

Tags: woocommerce, categories, product, sidebar

I have searched the forum and found people wanting to get rid of the sidebar when on the product category page. My issue is the opposite and I have not found someone raising it (so hopefully, the solution is easy):
the sidebar shows OK on the (standard woocommerce) shop page (based on woocommerce.php template) but when I click a product category in the sidebar of that same shop page, the product category page (based on woocommerce.php template as well) has no sidebar.
Has someone come across this issue?
(WordPress 4.9.4, woocommerce 3.3.3 (same issue on 3.3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your functions.php file, I would recommend that you use a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) or [plugin](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) for this. That way you won't lose your modifications when the theme gets updated.

```
add_action('wp', create_function("", "if (is_archive(array('product'))) remove_action( 'woo_main_after', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);") );
```